# What is the application layer specifically?

Tags: networking, operating-system, system-calls, application-layer

I was reading the ***Comptia network+ All in One Guide*** by **Mike Meyers**, and I came across this line:
*"The application layer does not refer to the applications themselves, rather it refers to the code built into the Operating System that enables making network aware applications."*

So my question is, do the functions like `connect`, `bind`, `listen` comprise of the application layer ?

Answer (score -1):

Application layer is later of osi model at application layer application layer facilitate users to user remaning 6 layers services.

Comment: Actually, the OSI model is simply a model that is not implemented in your OS. For example, the session and presentation layers are not implemented, and are part of the application layer, sometimes implemented by an application. The IP services model is closer to what the real world uses, but, again, it is just a model, and there is nothing that requires anything to follow it. Many things do not follow any of the models, or only pay lip service to a model. Do not get hung up on models.